# Is a Rackspace Cloud Server right for me?

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I have a Dedicated Virtual server plan with Media Temple right now and am looking to switch to a more reliable provider with a better machine. Right now I'm looking at Rackspace's Cloud Server plan, trying to read past the marketing text and see if this would work for me. Current stats for this fairly typical server situation:

- Code projects are mainly focused on Apache/PHP/MySQL, though I'd like to have the ability to run other servers (JBoss, Rails, etc.) as well
- Currently receiving ~2000 uniques per month. Monthly bandwidth usage ranges from 15 to 20 GB.
- Running Plesk Panel 10 to manage virtual hosts, though root access is still a must

The Cloud Server seems like a pretty good fit, and I'm considering the 2 GB RAM option as a starting point for the server. Is this a good choice for the amount of traffic the server is currently handling and the tasks that it is performing? If not — should I be looking for lower-volume solutions? I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Uniques are only good for business/marketing people. Those 2k uniques might make 1 page view or 1000. When you're talking to sys admin people tell us in page views.

Answer (score 0):

I use Rackspace to run the LAMP stack on it and am satisfied with the performance.

Rackspace provides root access to the VM and you can do whatever you want with it. Depending upon your architecture you can use the API's to add and remove servers, and resizes them too on the fly, ondemand scaling.